# JSP and HTML form

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to run a sql statement when a user selects from the dropdown menu.

My html:

```
<form action="listKeyword.jsp">
          <select name="item">
            <option value="buy">Buy</option>
            <option value="hold">Hold</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="sell">Sell</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

My JSP code:

```
<% 
        Dbase db = new Dbase();
        Connection conn = db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fyp", "root", "");
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String keyword = request.getParameter("item");
        //out.println(keyword);
        if(keyword == "buy"){
            out.println("buy statement");
            String query = "select numberofoccurence from stock WHERE name='buy';";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }else if(keyword == "sell"){
            String query = "select numberofoccurence from stock WHERE name='sell';";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }


    %>
```

It has no error at all. It just couldn't get into the if else statement. What could be the reason ? I am new to JSP.

Comment: What is the output of keyword string?

Comment: The value which I selected from the html page

Comment: use `"buy".equals(keyword)` etc. instead of direct reference comparison

Comment: Make use of String.equals instead '=='

Comment: It's generally best to use `.equals()` to compare two String's, just in case they haven't been interned. It could be that the value of the String is neither "buy" nor "sell". It might also be a non-exact match - check for uppercase/lowercase issues and whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered a million times! always use equals when it comes to strings so replace `if(keyword == "buy")...` with `if("buy".equals(keyword))`.

Comment: Or even better "buy".equals (keyword) to reduce nullchecks

Answer (score 0):

When checking `keyword` for equivalence to "buy" and "sell", don't use the `==` operator. You should use `.equals()` when you want to check string equality, because `==` is used to compare the reference.